# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager Caching

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I'm using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for my network functionality. Is there any way to know, before executing a network request, whether that request will be fulfilled from the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`cachedResponseForRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcache/1411817-cachedresponseforrequest?language=objc) for your [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcache?language=objc) and see if you get a cached response or not.

---

By the way, I'm not sure you should be using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` anymore because it relies upon the deprecated `NSURLConnection`. We would generally use `AFHTTPSessionManager` nowadays (which unfortunately is not `NSOperation`-based, likely requiring refactoring of your code).